# Adding an optional href to anchor tab using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a hyperlink on my template that is conditionally available. In the case when it's not available, I want it to still display but just be inactive.

This was my first attempt:

`<a ng-class="{denied: !data.CanManageLeadFields }">
   Lead Fields
</a>`

ng-class works appropriately. The denied class changes the pointer to default on the link. I was hoping the same principle would apply to the href attribute, but I have to eliminate the attribute itself, not just set it to a blank string. I can't seem to find anything to do this out of the box. Any ideas?

Comment: Showing a link with which the user can't interact, absent any other obvious feedback, seems like a UI nightmare.

Comment: Not only does Dave Thomas make a good burger, he makes a great point.

Comment: Why not use ng-href and make the attribute value # when disabled?

Comment: I was replacing "if positive, show a block, else show div block" logic. Trying to dry up the content a little,  because there's more than "Lead Fields" as the content.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I'm also styling it differently via CSS.

Comment: ng-switch is better way to handle this...